# how do I add a group to the Remote Desktop Users group on a local machine from the domain controller?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012

I'm working with a domain controller (WS 2012 R2) and several client machines (all Win7). I'd like to add a group called Support to the Remote Desktop Users group on every client machine. From looking around, it appears that this is not possible. I've tried `PSEXEC` (SysInternals) with mixed results (of the 2 machines I tried, I was only able to connect to one).

How can I add a user group to the Remote Desktop Users group on all machines connected to my domain controller? Doing it one by one is a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this directly via Group Policy:

- Computer Configuration

  - Preferences

    - Control Panel Settings

      - Local Users and Groups

Add Group

- Action: Update
- Group name: Remote Desktop Users (built-in)
- Members:

  - Add... DOMAIN\Support

This way you can even have separated support groups for different OUs.

Answer (score -2):

Group Policy Preferences - group membership.

--- Edit ---

Please feel free to fill in the gaps.  Group Policy is a core function of Active Directory domains.  Group Policy Preferences are an extension introduced with Win2k8/Vista that can be used to control things such as files, groups, [temporary] registry keys/values on your clients.  Try Googling "Group Policy Preferences" and read some of the MS how-to documents.  The topic is too large for a meaningful answer here.